# Prepared statement: PHP Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm writing a function `dbInsert()` to automate as much as possible the procedure and simplify the readability of my code and I'm having a problem with the prepared statement (previously tested and fully working).

This is the code:

```
$stmt = $GLOBALS['conn']->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.$dbColumnSTR.') VALUES ('.$qmSTR.')');
print_r($stmt);
$stmt->bind_param('"'.$dataTypeSTR.'"', $inputValueSTR);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Where

`$dbColumnSTR` = an imploded array with the columns' names *(name, code, price, shows)*

`$qmSTR` = an imploded array with as many `?` as the values are *(?, ?, ?, ?)*

`$dataTypeSTR` = an imploded array with all the values' types *(sssi)*

`$inputValueSTR` =  an imploded array with all the values *(test, DK4, 49.5, 2)*

I'm getting this as result of the query: `PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables`

Since the only thing I changed is not providing variables `$name, $code, $price, $shows` in `$stmt->bind_param()` but a string with the values directly, could it be that the problem? Otherwise what could it be?

This is how my query appears (I guess):

```
$stmt = $GLOBALS['conn']->prepare('INSERT INTO tabletest (name, code, price, shows) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param("sssi", est, DK4, 49.5, 2);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: `".$dataTypeSTR."` is nonsense.

Comment: `$inputValueSTR` is one value, not 4.

Comment: @deceze Why? Is it not the same providing `sssi` directly or into a variable?

Comment: Look at the `.`s those aren't concatenating. Your `binding` is `$stmt->bind_param(".sssi.", 'est, DK4, 49.5, 2');`

Comment: for php http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php for the query and for the binding http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: `bind_param` needs a separate argument for each parameter. You can't concatenate all the parameters into a single variable.

Comment: The first parameter is the data types as single letters. It only needs to be quoted if it is a string. `$stmt->bind_param($dataTypeSTR,` would be fine, or `$stmt->bind_param('ssss'` (if you had 4 strings being bound) You then need to pass in each index of the array as its own value.

Comment: @chris85 So the problem is the one I imagined while asking the question, that is I can't use a single variable `$inputValueSTR` containing all the imploded values even if separated by the comma, right?

Comment: Yes. With PDO you could just pass the full array of parameterized values to the `execute`. I dont think myqsli has anything like that. e.g. take `$inputValueSTR` pre-implode and `execute($inputValueSTR)` would work fine. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php see example 3.

Comment: @RyanVincent Please, don't even start. **DO NOT** "just build the query string". That's how you get injection bugs and that's how [bad things happen](http://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/).

Comment: @RyanVincent "Why bother" is not a form of insisting that I've ever heard of. That sure doesn't sound like always to me.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is super easy to do in PDO, `execute()` just takes an associative array so you can pass in arbitrary variables that bind to named placeholders. By comparison `mysqli` is a giant pain to use.

Answer (score -1):

you should just use this:

```
//I assume that you have data to store something like this

$inputValueSTR=array("sss",$value_first, $value_second, $value_third);
$inputValueSTR= implode(", ", $inputValueSTR);
$stmt->bind_param($inputValueSTR);
```

first parameter in the array is for data type in the corresponding index of value. you can see it her : [mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
.

as I'm seeing your final is: `$stmt->bind_param("ssdi", est, DK4, 49.5, 2);`
it should be `$stmt->bind_param("ssdi", "est", "DK4", 49.5, 2);`
or

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssi", "est", "DK4", "49.5", 2);
```

Comment: that's why I have given the reference to understand it, and change accordingly, if required.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I'm doing using two different imploded arrays? `$dataTypeSTR` = sssi, `$inputValueSTR` = test, DK4, 49.5, 2 => `$stmt->bind_param($dataTypeSTR, $inputValueSTR);`  | If I put all into a single imploded array should it work?

Comment: You have the right idea on the first line, then you go and jump off a cliff on the second.

Comment: The OP doesn't want a static call. This needs to be dynamic.

Comment: @brigo, it may be due to quote("" or '') issue as I have last pointed while editing the answer.